# MongoDb Connection timeout in Azure Datafactory while Sync Data

Tags: mongodb, azure-data-factory, copy-database-wizard

I have created one dataset in azure datafactory for connect mongodb.

While configuration i have added MongoDb connection string and it's show me connection successful. As per shown in image [view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuAyK.png)

After that i have configure whole pipeline with proper configuration.

Now i am facing issue while run that pipeline.

I am getting below error as Mongodb connection is not valid.

Operation on target **Copydataset1** failed: Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorMongoDbConnectionTimeout,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Connection to MongoDB server is timeout. This is usually caused by invalid connection string.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.MongoDbV2Connector,''Type=System.TimeoutException,Message=A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = ReadPreferenceServerSelector{ ReadPreference = { Mode : Primary } }, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "Automatic", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "**192.0.0.1:27017**" }", EndPoint: "**192.0.0.1:27017**", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown" }] }.,Source=MongoDB.Driver.Core,'

**NOTE**: This ip 192.0.0.1:27017 is only for example.